# CSS Transition another div (SASS) and itself //edit load order issue

Tags: css, hover, sass, css-transitions

I am trying to get it so that when one div is hovered over another div is animated whilst at the same time the hovered div also animates.

so far I have it so that one div works as I want but the other div only animates itself. Here's the sass code

```
@mixin four04-text-label-transitions($class: false, $side:false) {

.#{$side}-label:hover + .#{$class}, .#{$class}:hover {

@if ($class == "fa-home"){
  margin-left: $fa-icon-left - 0.4rem;
  bottom: $bottom + 0.4rem;
} @else if ($class == "fa-search"){
  bottom: $bottom-middle + 0.4rem;
} @else if ($class == "fa-envelope-o"){
  margin-left: $fa-icon-right + 0.4rem;
  bottom: $bottom + 0.4rem;
}

}

.#{$class}:hover + .#{$side}-label, .#{$side}-label:hover {
   opacity: 1;
   @include transition-delay(0);
 }
}
```

Classes: fa-home, fa-search, fa-envelope-o
sides: left, middle, right

At the moment if I hover over fa-home for example, fa-home moves up and to the left and left-label goes from opacity 0 to opacity 1. However, if I hover of left-label; the opacity goes from 0-1 but fa-home doesn't move.

I have included a fiddle below. It's a very basic representation of what is going on. You can see if you hover over the third square down (it's a bit buggy in fiddle) it will animate to the right and the words Report Dead Link will appear. However, if you hover over Report dead link, it appears but the square doesn't move.

I have also included the app.css (compiled sass) stylesheet from my site with all the styles in so you can see it more clear and the HTML is taken from my site too.

http://jsfiddle.net/8fCMA/21/

**I want both elements to animate both themselves and their siblings.**

////////EDIT//////////

It seams to have a problem with the load order of the DOM.

if fa-home comes before left-label; fa-home can animate both elements but left-label can not animate fa-home

if the order is reversed so are the effects (left-label can control both, but not fa-home)

**is there a way to have both elements animate each other without the use of a third element and z-indexes overlapping each other?**

Answer (score 0):

OK it seems that the sibling selector only selects elements lower in the DOM a work around that I have came up with is to put the markup like this

```
<div class="icon-text left-label label-top">Go to Homepage</div>
<i class="fa fa-inverse fa-home fa-5x"></i>
<div class="icon-text left-label">Go to Homepage</div>
```

Then set .label-top to have a higher z-index.

It doesn't seem like a very good way to do it but it works for now.

I would appreciate any other solutions (without resorting to JS)